# Heroku, Java Web app - free dynos Procfile - How to create proper Procfile

Tags: java, heroku, web-applications, deployment, procfile

I'm trying to upload my 1st Java Web app to the web but I can't handle the Procfile. After deploy, there is info about successfully deploy but when I try to run the app there are an error and server logs seems to indicate that Procfile is empty / does not exist.

In server resources there is following dyno:

```
java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war
```

and in thetutorial there is
"Your Procfile will look something like this:"

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* HelloWorld
```

but I don't udnerstand what is happening here. I know only that there should be web: at the beggining for web-app I don't understand the rest of it. Can some one help me undrstand it so I could create proper Procfile for my app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have heroku installed and if you have only .jsp and .class you can do as it follows, and you don't need a procfile:

`$ heroku create <app_name>`

Create a WAR file of your app in Eclipse for example:
Right click on the project > Export > WAR file

then you have to deploy it to heroku:

```
$ heroku war:deploy <path_to_war_file> --app <app_name>
```

then you'll see the app going to heroku, some logs and blah blah blah. After that you can open your application:

```
$ heroku open --app <app_name>
```

Simple. But if you need some help about procfile, take a look [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile)

Comment: Man u SAVED me! :) Thank you so much. It is working! :)
I still don't understand Prcfile construction though. I mean especially command: those are predefined or I shall create one on my own? :)